# How to write mercurial hooks on windows?

Tags: mercurial

I want to add a hook to my repository. I can't work out where i need to put the hook file. The hgrc file is as follows:

```
[hooks]
precommit.test =  precommithook
```

Location is C:\Code\RepoTest.hg\hgrc

Hook file is:

```
echo "hello world"
```

Location is C:\Code\RepoTest.hg\precommithook

When i run

> hg commit -m"test"

from the command line i get

```
running hook precommit.test: precommithook
'precommithook' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
abort: precommit.test hook exited with status 1
```

I've tried various paths but nothing works.

Most of the examples i googled with regards to Mercurial hooks are Unix based.

Is it possible to write hooks in a powershell?

Comment: I take it this a batch file? Do you definitely have the .bat extension on it? It's just not clear from your example and I don't want to assume.

Comment: It could be a batch file. I have added the .bat extension but i have to add the full path to reach the file. C:\Code\RepoTest\.hg\precommithook.bat Anyway around this?

Comment: Relative path maybe: precommit.test = .\precommithook.bat. The path you can use will depend on what path the command is running under, maybe add an echo of the %CD% variable into the batch file to see where it thinks it's running and then that might help identify the path you need to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Hooks doc, hook must be executable in given environment program, it haven't predefined location, but have to be found by OS.

Thus:

- For pure Windows, hook must be named `precommithook.bat`
- It must be placed into dir in $PATH or full path used in hook definition

As result, with

`precommit.test =  z:\precommit.bat` in hgrc

`@echo off`

`echo Hello World` in z:\precommit.bat

I have on commit attempt

```
>hg commit -m "Edits"
Hello World
```

Comment: Do you know how i can get the bat file to return status 1 so i can abort the commit attempt?

Comment: @AlP `exit /B 1`, read also http://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/returning-error-code-on-scripts-how-to.html http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html for deeper details